# How do I query within multiple levels of embedded documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume I have a MongoDB (4.2.9) collection structured like:

```
{
    _id: 'Alice',
    pets: {
        'Marmaduke': {
            'age': 9
        },
        'Clifford': {
            'age': 3
        }
    }
},
{
    _id: 'Bob',
    pets: {
        'Odie': {
            'age': 6
        }
    }
}
```

How would I query for all owners with pets aged over 5?  Ideally the projection would only include the matching embedded documents down to the search field, so the result set would look just like the example without Clifford.

This seems to me like it should be easily answerable with the documentation, but all I can find are operations matching arrays of embedded documents, and not documents of embedded documents.  I get the feeling that modeling arrays of documents is far more common, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around that as (in my use case) the pets are uniquely identified by their owner and name, and an update operation on Marmaduke should look like:

```
{
    _id: 'Alice'
},
{
    $set: {
        pets.Marmaduke.age: 10
    }
}
```

rather than having to find `{_id: 'Marmaduke'}` in an array.  However, if I should be thinking about embedded documents in a different way then please explain.

Comment: Please let me know if this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EUgT_mfY8bg) is what you need.

Comment: It looks like that does the trick, thank you.  So the simplest solution really is to convert the object to an array, search it, and convert it back?  Do you know if there is a significant performance penalty or are `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` optimized out in the query planning?

Comment: Optimally I think you'd want to set `pets` as an `array` instead of an immediate `object` - e.g. you would set it as `"pets": [{"name": "Clifford", "age": 3}]` -, because, besides making the query more expensive with `$objectToArray`, you would likely have to use a sparse index.